# How do I create multiple records from a single record?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

Assume I have a record in stream A with the following fields:
`{timestamp, json}`

Example Record:

```
{"row":{"columns":[1678710830000, {"1": "abc", "2": "bcd", "3": "xyz"}]}}
```

What would the query be if I want to produce the following records to Stream B (or table)?

The imaginary fields could be
`{timestamp, fieldA, fieldB}`

```
{"row":{"columns":[1678710830000, "1", "abc"]}}
{"row":{"columns":[1678710830000, "2", "bcd"]}}
{"row":{"columns":[1678710830000, "3", "xyz"}]}}
```

Comment: Ksql shouldn't be used here, unless you want to programmatically create many queries similar to the answer below... You can use Kafka Streams flatmap function for this. What have you tried on your own?

Answer (score -1):

I would create 3 different "STREAM AS" with different SELECT clause..

Example :

```
CREATE STREAM B1 WITH ( KAFKA_TOPIC='DestTopic' ) 
    AS SELECT TimeStamp, FieldA, ValueA 
         FROM streamA 

CREATE STREAM B2 WITH ( KAFKA_TOPIC='DestTopic' ) 
    AS SELECT TimeStamp, FieldB, ValueB 
         FROM streamA 

CREATE STREAM B3 WITH ( KAFKA_TOPIC='DestTopic' ) 
    AS SELECT TimeStamp, FieldC, ValueC 
         FROM streamA
```

Note that all 3 streams write to the same topic.

Comment: This wont be possible since there could be over 1000 values in the json/map

Comment: Values within the array aren't selectable like this